# Issue with determining height of drop-down-menu internal elements with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Currently I have an Ajax call that gets notifications that a populated into a drop down. After these notifications are appended into the drop down div I want to animate the drop down to open up to the total height of all the elements.

Currently this function is called on click:

```
function showNotificationDropDown() {
    if ($('#notification-dropdown-box').height() == 0) {
              // removing old content
        $("#notifi-box").remove();
              // this is to show the loading spinner
        $('#notification-dropdown-box').animate({ height: "120px" }, 100);
              //shows loading spinner while call is being made
        var spinner = $("<div class='spinner-sm'> </div>");
        $('#notification-dropdown-box').html(spinner);

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/GetNotifications",
           traditional: true
        }).fail(function () {
           alert('AJAX failed');
        }).complete(function () {
           spinner.remove();
        }).done(function (html) {
           //after the html data is obtained it is appended into the notification
           //after it is appended the notification must drop down to the hieght of this html data
           $('#notification-dropdown-box').append(html).done(expandNotificationDropDown());
           return false;
        });

        return false;
    }
        return false;
    };
```

Now the function that expands the Notification has issues:

```
    function expandNotificationDropDown() {
        $('#notification-dropdown-box').children().each(function () {
            var totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
            alert(totalHeight);
            if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
                $('#notification-dropdown-box').animate({ height: totalHeight }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
```

I use the alert to test for the height on each pass. My issue is that all I get from the alert is "NaN". Once the last notification piece is added to the height no animation is done since no height is obtained.

What is the reason for this? All the children within the main #notification-dropdown-box do not have a written height but my research tells me that outerHeight should still obtain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code totalHeight is undefined. undefined + numer is NaN. Try this:

```
function expandNotificationDropDown() {
    var totalHeight = 0;
    $('#notification-dropdown-box').children().each(function () {
        totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
    alert(totalHeight);
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        $('#notification-dropdown-box').animate({ height: totalHeight }, 100);
    }
}
```